Trackeo de un PDF
espero que todo vaya bien. Escribo porque necesito pedir ayuda. Me gustaría rastrear un PDF, específicamente para ver si se ha abierto, etc. Hay algunas aplicaciones de pago que funcionan, pero al final, el archivo es un poco diferente de un PDF y debe abrirse a través de un navegador. Necesito poder reenviarlo por WhatsApp. Le pregunté a ChatGPT cómo podría hacer esto, y me respondió que es posible insertar un píxel de seguimiento. Me gustaría saber si esto es posible.
Intenté seguir todos los pasos de ChatGPT, pero hubo cosas que no pude descifrar. Hasta ahora, lo que hice fue crear una imagen de 1x1, subirla a Imgur y luego redirigir el enlace a través de PizzaRedirect, lo que te permite ver si se accedió al enlace. El problema es que, al insertar la imagen en el PDF, hay que hacer clic en el enlace. ¿Sabe cómo puedo solucionar esto? ¿Hay otro método?
Muchas gracias por su tiempo. Estaría muy agradecido si alguien pudiera ayudarme. (Por cierto, no sé nada sobre programación, pero podría aprender si es necesario.)

No se puede. El pdf nació para ser portable, multiplataforma y "solo lectura". Esta última es la gracia de ese tipo de archivos. Sabemos que si se puede editar un pdf con las herramientas adecuadas, pero ese es otro cuento. Una forma de saber si el pdf ha sido entregado podría ser subir el archivo a un webserver y entregarle un enlace a cada usuario tipo http://.../el_archivo.pdf?trackid=dW51c3Vhcml... donde la última cadena es el id de seguimiento (base64) del usuario (correo, usuario, etc). Obviamente necesitarás programación para procesar el request cuando el usuario le de clic al enlace.

No se si te funcione, pero en mi caso me han enviado propuestas comerciales por correo desde un servicio que, supongo, al hacerle clic le avisa al proponente que abrí el contenido. Es comercial, de pago, pero puedes echarle un vistazo a ver si cumple tus necesidades.
